Ways to integrate: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}\, dx$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^4}\, dx$$
it's not apparent to me how to evaluate this integral, it's antiderivative is not explicit and since it's upper bound is $+\infty$ i cannot use: $$\frac{1}{1+x^4}=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^nx^{4n}$$
Because i'd be outside it's radius of convergence. I tried a couple of substitutions like: $y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=\tan{\theta}$ but to no avail.
I also attempted contour integration using a slice of lenght $R$ (which is going to be taken to infinity in the limit) and an angle $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to dodge the poles of the complex valued function. Still didn't manage to get it done. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
